# How do I create a internal properties file for spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I currently have a external properties file and it's being called by input stream. but when I upload my jar file to cloud foundry my application would not run.

**code snippet**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);


    Properties prop = new Properties();

    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        Date sysDate = new Date();
        String dateString = sysDate.toString();
        logger.info(" Application Started Time : " + dateString);

        input = new
        FileInputStream("C:/Users/Jackie/workspace/springApplication/myConfig.properties");
        prop.load(input);
```

Inside my properties file I have alot of text and it is used in my java app. As I was doing research it seems like I need to change my properties file to a spring boot format? Is that correct?

**properties snippet**

```
mailhost=mailman@mail.com
mailToException=TheReal_mailman@mail.com
mailwhengreen = TheReal_mailman@mail.com
mailTo = TheReal_mailman@mail.com
mailFrom = messenger21@yahoo.com
mailFromwhengreen = messenger21@yahoo.com
subject= You got mail!
```

Here is the logs from cloud foundry.

[errors from cf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyOVo.png)

Comment: It is extremly unlikely that cloud foundry will have any file at C:/Users/Jackie/workspace/springApplication/myConfig.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer below will do fine when your properties file is static, loaded once at application startup and does not change during application lifecycle.
If you need to parse properties files during application runtime then Spring profiles are not correct place of that and you indeed need to handle properties at your own (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations-filesystemresource should help you there)

There is no need to read and parse properties file on your own.

Easiest think you could do, is use profiles.
You you enable profile named `someProfile`, then spring will look for properties file named `application-someProfile.properties`.

If found external (outside of your packaged jar) file will be used. Otherwise internal (packaged inside your jar) file will be used. That is clarified on 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config

> Properties are considered in the following order:
>
> (...)
>
> 12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar
>       (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants) Profile-specific
> 13. application properties packaged inside your jar
>       (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)

It is perfectly fine to have profile without matching properties file.

Profile is activated by adding `@Profile("production")` on any `@Configuration` class.

Active profiles may be also listed using `spring.profiles.active` environment variable (you may set this variable when starting application).

To read value of properties, you may do one of

- `@Autowire` instance of `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` into your class and call `getProperty`
- inject String variable annotated with @Value("${propertyName}")

Check http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html 
for more details about Spring Boot properties.

Check http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html for more information about profiles.

In case of errors in your properties file, you should get errors at application startup (during context loading). To check loaded properties you may use http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

`env` endpoint will be most usefull, because it will list

- all enabled profiles
- all loaded properties files
- all loaded properties

Comment: Thank you! To clarify I basically need to rewrite my external properties text file and create a java class ?

Comment: external (or internal) properties file is fine. To load it, you need just enabled profile and correctly named properties file. Spring has sophisticated properties resolution order http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config you are interested in points 12,13